# Yii2 - find page number by Object

Tags: pagination, yii2, dataprovider

I need you help. I trying to find right solution for my task.

Imagen, I have a **books**

```
id | name
--------
1  | book1
2  | book2
```

and books has **chapters**

```
id | name     | book_id
-------------------
1  | chapter1 | 1
2  | chapter2 | 1
```

There is **page for book** and another **page for chapters** with pagination limit 1 record of chapter on page.

So, what I'm trying to do: on the **book page** I have **chapters links** and I need to generate links to **chapter page** with **page pagination** attribute.
Question is how to detect page number of needed chapter?

For some reason I'm using `ArrayDataProvider` instead of `ActiveDataProvider` in controller method for **chapters list**. Your answers can be based on `ActiveDataProvider`. *Index* or *PK* of chapter cannot be used for page number in my case.

```
//Controller action (chapters page with pagination)

public function actionRead($id)
{
    $this->layout = 'main-pure-header';

    $query = Chapter::find()->where(['prose_id' => $id])
        ->orderBy('id asc');

    $chapterPages = ChapterHelper::explodeChapter($query->all(), self::PER_PAGE);
    $chapterProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $chapterPages,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 1,
            'pageSizeParam' => false
        ]
    ]);

    return $this->render('/prose/large-all', [
        'chapterProvider' => $chapterProvider
    ]);
}

//VIEW (chapters page with pagination)

<?= LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $chapterProvider->pagination,
    'maxButtonCount' => 0,
    'prevPageLabel' => 'Next page',
    'nextPageLabel' => 'Prev page'
]); ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Updated #1**

Here is chapters list on the book page

```
<?php foreach ($prose->chapters as $chapter) { ?>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <?= Html::a($chapter->name, ['large/read', 'id' => $chapter->prose->id, 'page' => '???']) ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: "Question is how to detect page number of needed chapter?" - how do you define the "needed chapter" when on a book page?

Comment: @ajmedway At book page I have chapters list found by relations. Sure I can generate link to each chapter by chapter model id... But I need pagination that I can navigate to next or prev chapter on the chapter page. See the Updated #1 in my post